# Flutter When running app on Android a Manifest Merger failed error: different values is found

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I am receiving the following error when I try to test my app on Android:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Overlay manifest:package attribute declared at AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-36 value=(com.carbery.qiGangApp)
> has a different value=(com.carbery.qiGangApp) declared in main manifest at AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-29
> Suggestion: remove the overlay declaration at AndroidManifest.xml   and place it in the build.gradle:
> flavorName {
> applicationId = "com.carbery.qiGangApp"
> }

A little history, I did use another app as a template for starting this one and so I changed the name and the applicationId. Originally when running the app for Android I received the same error as above, but with the old name. I then did a Find through all my files and changed the old name to the new one. The correct name is: com.carbery.qiGangApp

However I am still receiving the error, now even though the two values it refers to, look to be the same correct ones.

As I come from an Ios back ground, I am not so familiar with the Android set up. So any help with solving this would really be gratefully received.

Many thanks

Comment: Try to check the app level **build.gradle** file if it has the same package name in the **androidmanifest.xml**

Comment: Thanks for the contact. Yes the app level, build.gradle has the same settings: defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.carbery.qiGangApp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate your problem it seems that you need to sync your package name across multiple **AndroidManifest.xml** files.

[image]

Try to update this 3 **AndroidManifest.xml** files:

[image]